# How to re-enter town after stealing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In an Inn, while trying to speak with someone I accidentally picked up an item, stealing it. The Inn's owner and wife immediately began attacking and chased me out of town. Every time I go back into the Inn, the two immediately recognize me and chase me out of town again.

Is there anything I can do to get forgiveness in the Inn?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Hold that owns that town, and get caught by a guard.  Pay your fine or serve your time in prison to be forgiven of your crimes.  Note that you'll lose your stolen items when searched.

If you've progressed a certain amount in the Thieves' Guild questline, you'll be able to bribe the guard instead.  This costs more than paying your fine but the guard doesn't search you, allowing you to keep your stolen items.

Comment: If you have enough rank in a certain hold,  they will turn a blind eye to your actions aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have committed a minor crime, your best option is to [yield](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Yield). In Skyrim, you can yield by simply sheathing your weapon. The button depends on your platform.

- Computer: <kbd>R</kbd>
- PlayStation: **Square**
- Xbox: **X**

When you yield to NPCs, they will often forgive minor crimes. If this does not work, you may have committed a larger offense. You may need to seek out a guard, to trigger having to pay a fine/ going to jail.

If you resist arrest, yielding will also calm down guards. You will still have to answer for your crimes, but the guards will no longer treat you as hostile.

Comment: Odd, if I enter the Inn even unarmed they still attack.

Comment: IIRC, sometimes it does not always trigger. I especially recall that to be the case with unarmed, since you do not have a weapon to sheathe or unsheathe. In fact, I recall it being the deliberate action of **sheathing infront of the NPC** that had the correct response. If all else fails, try holding down the button, instead.

Comment: Played long time ago  but from what I remember, the yield option works only when you're about to be attacked by guards, not by citizens.

Comment: Its buggy, but yeah, it works on civies. Saved my butt a couple of times. The only exception is if the AI is forefully aggressive - this can even work on passives like giants and mammoths, sometimes.